# Storing groups of words in hashtable

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

I have an ArrayList of words, and I want to compare the words against each other, to store them in a HashTable (in groups of anagrams).

I know how to compare **two** words to test if they are an anagram, but I can't figure out how to compare a longer list of words.

For example:

- There 10 words in the list
- 5 of them are anagrams of each other
- 2 of them are also anagrams of each other (but not of the first group)
- So, 3 groups; 1 group of one set of anagrams (5 words), 1 group for the other set (2 words), and 1 group (3 words) of random words

How do I compare the 10 words to find those 5+2 anagrams, and store those anagrams groups (separately) into a hashtable?

**EDIT:**

The code I have for comparing two words:

```
public static boolean isAnagram(String firstWord, String secondWord) {

    boolean anagram;
    if (firstWord.length() != secondWord.length()) {
        return false;
    }
    firstWord = firstWord.toLowerCase();
    secondWord=secondWord.toLowerCase();
    char[] c1 = firstWord.toCharArray();
    char[] c2 = secondWord.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(c1);
    Arrays.sort(c2);
    String sc1 = new String(c1);
    String sc2 = new String(c2);
    if (sc1.equals(sc2)) {
        System.out.println("ANAGRAMS");
    } else {
        System.out.println("NOT ANAGRAMS");
    }
    return sc1.equals(sc2);
}
```

I'm sure this could be adapted to work with comparing an unlimited amount of strings. Then the next dilemma is ensuring that the separate groups of anagrams are stored in the hashtable.

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: Brute force solution would be to compare every word with other words and store whenever you find an Anagram.

Comment: The simplest way would be to loop over all the words and compare each word *w* with the other 9. The make a hashtable: *w* -> anagrams of *w*.

Comment: @Bhargav but how can that be made to work if there is more than 1 group of anagrams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class AnagramDetector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("Abc");
        words.add("cba");
        words.add("bca");
        words.add("bc");
        words.add("ba");
        words.add("ab");

        MultiValueMap<String, String> res = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        words.stream().forEach(word -> {
            String key = getAnagramKey(word);
            res.add(key, word);
        });
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    public static String getAnagramKey(String word) {
        char[] c = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        return new String(c);
    }

}
```

UPDATE for Hashtable:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;

public class AnagramDetector {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        words.add("Abc");
        words.add("cba");
        words.add("bca");
        words.add("bc");
        words.add("ba");
        words.add("ab");

        Hashtable<String, List<String>> res = new Hashtable<>();
        words.stream().forEach(word -> {
            String key = getAnagramKey(word);
            List<String> anWords = res.get(key);
            if (anWords == null) {
                anWords = new ArrayList<>();
                res.put(key, anWords);
            }
            anWords.add(word);
        });
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    public static String getAnagramKey(String word) {
        char[] c = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        return new String(c);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I really want to use a HashTable as that is the object I'm teaching myself about.

Comment: How do you truncate hashtable "rows" (keys) that only contain one word?

Comment: I don't. You can go iterate the entries leaving only values where list size > 1.

Comment: How would you omit anagram lists that contain only one (1) word? 

The only way I've managed to do it (and it's cheating a bit) is to use an `if` statement for printing the hashtable, which only prints the key if the size of the list associated with the key is greater than 1: `int i = 1; for (String key : res.keySet()) { List<String> value = res.get(key); if (value.size() > 1) { System.out.println("Anagram " + i + ": " + value); i++;}}`

Comment: Yes. That's fine

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have already figured out you can sort the strings to find out if two strings are anagrams.

You can store each string in the hash table when the key is the sorted string. For example, string "CBA" will be saved in spot "ABC", then it is easy enough to check if an anagram of a string already appeared.

If you actually need the strings themselves then you can store them in list of lists, or a better way is to use a Multimap.